Spring Boot Application Failing to Connect to MySQL Database in Jenkins Pipeline
I’m working on a basic Spring Boot web application using MySQL. When I try to run it in Jenkins, I encounter an issue where it fails to connect to the database. The application works perfectly on localhost, and the database is accessible. Below are the details of my setup and the error I am encountering.

pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven "MAVEN3"
        jdk "OracleJDK17"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Fetch code') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/kuanmol/crud-stud'
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn package -DskipTests'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    echo 'Now Archiving it...'
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('UNIT TEST') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
        }
    }
}

pom.xml Configuration:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>studentcrud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>studentcrud</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

ApplicationProperties

`spring.application.name=studentcrud`
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb`
`spring.datasource.username=root`
`spring.datasource.password=anmolkumar`
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`
`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`


error log:

:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.3)

2024-09-07T12:04:45.581Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] c.e.s.StudentcrudApplicationTests        : Starting StudentcrudApplicationTests using Java 17.0.12 with PID 9444 (started by jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/please hoja)
2024-09-07T12:04:45.584Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] c.e.s.StudentcrudApplicationTests        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-09-07T12:04:46.655Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-09-07T12:04:46.737Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 67 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-09-07T12:04:47.490Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo \[name: default\]
2024-09-07T12:04:47.565Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
2024-09-07T12:04:47.613Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-09-07T12:04:48.055Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-09-07T12:04:48.093Z  INFO 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-09-07T12:04:49.847Z  WARN 9444 --- \[studentcrud\] \[           main\] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) \~\[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final\]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) \~\[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final\]

\[INFO\]
\[INFO\] Results:
\[INFO\]
\[ERROR\] Errors:
\[ERROR\]   StudentcrudApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for \[WebMergedContextConfiguration@2fb48970 testClass = com.example.studentcrud.StudentcrudApplicationTests, locations = \[\], classes = \[com.example.studentcrud.StudentcrudApplication\], contextInitializerClasses = \[\], activeProfiles = \[\], propertySourceDescriptors = \[\], propertySourceProperties = \["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"\], contextCustomizers = \[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1c742ed4, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@69c81773, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@210ab13f, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@71687585, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@1f9f6368, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@d06be235\], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null\]
\[INFO\]


Details:
Maven tests run successfully on my local machine with mvn test and mvn test -X.
My web application works fine on localhost, and the MySQL database is accessible.
I’m looking for help to resolve this issue in the Jenkins environment. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Want build success.

where is your mysql db running? is it installed locally as a program? or as a docker container? Where is jenkins running? Is it a local instance or hosted somewhere else?

locally installed mysql

well if mysql is locally installed and Jenkins is NOT local there is no good way for you to access local mysql (you could set up your ip address to be publicly accessible but I would not recommend that - local db is for local development - for jenkins you should either consider testcontainers or host db elsewhere)

like i using jenkins on ec2 instance thats why it happening?

if i put database on rds then it will work?

yes, database has to be publicly accessible for other apps (in this case Jenkins) to be able to access it. Yes, RDS (or any other publicly hosted DB) would work. I would question the idea of hosting a DB only for tests, since DBs cost money we usually only host them for the purpose of applications not for tests. But to answer your question, yes that works

If you are doing tests then i would recommend running Jenkins locally.
